# Mongo Shell doesn't return all matching documents with the find() query

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql

When I run this query, the mongo shell doesn't return all the documents that are in the database collection:

```
db.collection.find().pretty()
```

Only a fraction of the actual content is shown. When I head over to the MongoDB Compass GUI, the data is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that at the very end of the output there's the following line:

```
Type "it" for more
```

As suggested, typing "it" and hitting enter fetches more records from the query. Repeat until it says "no cursor". See also [Change the mongo Shell Batch Size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-mongo-shell/#change-the-mongo-shell-batch-size).

Answer (score 0):

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = [maxnumber you need]
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 300
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.